# How can I remove space at top of the 'recycleview's layout'?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dddddddasdfaf2fdsafdd"/>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

list_item.card.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                                    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
                                    card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                                    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="dafdafda"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[layoutmonitor captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ1TZ.png)

I make layout with CoordinatorLayout and RecyclerView. Building and launching is succes. But I have a small problem. As you see capture image, there is space above recyclerview. I seems recyclerview's space(top margin), but I never defined margin or padding.

How to remove this top space margin?

Comment: Do the list items have a margin/padding? Do you have a divider item decorator added to the recyclerview?

Comment: @DmitriTimofti there is any divider and margin/padding in listitem. I think, that margin is own of recyclerview. and no item decorator.

Comment: Could you show us layout of listitem ?

Comment: @Gorio I added list item layout code. Thanks.

Comment: I found answer. The main reason is that 'android:fitsSystemWindows="true"' property in the 'AppBarLayout'. This property is maybe perfomed to having top margin of status bar height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your layout_height in AppBarLayout and Toolbar was  set with value..

But, try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dddddddasdfaf2fdsafdd" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and see the result

[image]